# How to get the UserName of the PDA/Windows Mobile using .Net CF 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

well, this works great on a non Windows Mobile:

```
string user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

but, what I am looking for is how to get the name of the user on a Windows Mobile 5.0 and higher!

I tried the search feature, but unfortunately didn't find anything yet!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SystemState.OwnerName to get the name of the owner of the device, if they have filled that information in.

There is no currently logged on user for windows mobile devices.